# Push and pull online software solution

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

#### Current Situation

In our office environment before we moved over to Office 365, we designed Excel workbooks to cover our admin tasks, these workbooks were unique to each member of staff.  All staff workbooks were able in real time to access data held in other workbooks that were held on the office server. So workbooks that held customer information and workbooks that held pricing information would feed into quoting workbooks for example.

#### Since Moving to 365

Since moving over to 365 we have come to realise that Excel is unable in this environment to link to other outside sources making our workbooks unable to update information from source files in real time, or at least by itself at some point, say upon opening for instance.

#### What I am Looking For

I need somebody to point me towards a solution to this preferably a Microsoft 365 solution that can either handle Excel workbooks, or that work in a similar way so that i can use it to set up our admin systems without it being too much of a trauma, but would be open to alternatives.